# Sqlalchmey CheckContraint that checks multiple columns

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So we tried searching a lot here but none of the solutions seems to have answered what we are looking for. So, we using flask's sqlalchemy which is connected to the Postgres database. We have a user table that stores users phone number and related to users phone numbers we have the other two columns namely **is_primary** (is a boolean value that determines if this is user's primary phone number) and **current** (which is another boolean value that determines if this is users current phone no).

```
class Phones(PrimaryCol, DeletedCol, UserTable, IDTable, Base):
    

    __tablename__ = "phones"
    phone = Column(String(50))
    current = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_primary = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    CheckConstraint(
            "(NOT is_primary OR current OR (is_primary = true AND current = true))",
            name="my_contraint",
        )
```

Now the issue is about the check constraint. Let me tell you what we are trying to achieve with that. So we want to add a multi-column validation that if **is_primary** is true then the **current** has to be true by default and cannot be false and if  **is_primary** is false then **current** can be either true or false. So seeing the pattern used for UniqueContraint([How is a unique constraint across three columns defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895207/how-is-a-unique-constraint-across-three-columns-defined))  we tried to emulate this in CheckContraint but is not working by that we mean it allows current to be T/f if is_primary is true. ( which is what we do not want and want database to throw an error). Can someone please help us with how can we add a CheckContraint that performs check on multicolumn values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a truth table for easy understanding:

```
p | c | result
--------------
T | T | valid
T | F | invalid
F | T | valid
F | F | valid
```

The only condition you want to avoid is `(is_primary and not current)`, so make your constraint `not (is_primary and not current)`, which can be reduced to `(not is_primary or current)`.

```
p | c | not is_primary or current
------------------------------------
T | T | T
T | F | F
F | T | T
F | F | T
```

(conversion remembered from Digital Computer Logic class because NAND gates were cheap).

Comment: @AaryanBHAGAT Thank you for the fixes!

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but it is still allowing me to enter the invalid case  :/

Comment: @NirajChowdhary  Can you please edit your answer to show your updated code and your table definition from inside of `psql`?  Use `\d phones` to get it.

Comment: Hey Mike,
Thanks a ton it worked. So on inspecting psql I saw there was no check constraint added so in order to bring that change I first migrated the db and then  added check contraint with your condition in the generated script and upgraded the db and thats it it started working